# Convert AC grid to DC and back to AC grid same phase

Tags: transistors, converter, power-engineering, ac-dc, dc-ac

I would like to execute long time running transistor switch tests with high currents. I would like to source AC power from grid, convert it to DC, pass through my transistor switch, after that I want to convert left power (some of the power will be radiated as heat from transistor and wires) back to AC and push it back to the grid. Simply I do not want to waste that energy into heat on some resistive load for example. In my opinion ordinary AC/DC converter on input and grid tie DC/AC converter (this converter have to follow sine wave from grid, I call it grid tie, I do not know whether it is proper name for such) will do the job, but my friends, which are more electrical engineers than I am (I'm software engineer actually), said that it will not work, but they are unable to explain why. I do not want to interfere with existing building electrical installation, I just want to connect to socket in wall with both my converters. What can you say about that, will it do the work, and if not why, and may how can I execute my tests in different way?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it will work. The DC/AC converter would be a grid-tied inverter. You may or may not be able to buy products that can be simply wired together. This site is for specific questions about electrical engineering and design and theory. detailed Instructions for building or buying such a system is not something that can be provided here. Judging from your stated qualifications, it is quite unlikely that you could design and build such a system. Purchasing products and getting them to work together may not be possible either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about buying products or designing a complex system. It is not a specific electrical engineering design or theory question.

Comment: Put the energy recovery on the DC side (boost DC-DC convertor).

Comment: You may find it easier to skip the feed back into the grid part and just recover everything on the DC side and just replenish the power from the losses in your test circuit by feeding in on the DC side with a AC/DC.

Comment: Re, "I would like to execute long time running...tests" If you read the kind of magazines that testing-lab people read, you will find advertisements for things called "bidirectional power supply" and "regenerative load." Google those! You might find exactly what you are looking for.